# Symfony (Doctrine) : accessing nestedset root element

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, nested-sets

I'm trying to get the root element of a nested set tree.

Here is the scenario:

I have a category table wich act as a nested set

```
Category:
  actAs:
    NestedSet:
      hasManyRoots: true
      rootColumnName: root_id
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: false }
```

and a Video table

```
Video:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    ...
  relations:
    Categories:
      class: Category
      refClass: CategoryVideo
      local: video_id
      foreign: category_id
      foreignAlias: Videos
```

Here is my problem: let's say a video is in the "Action" category and "Action" is a child of "Film", when I call getCategories() from my Video object, I only have the "Action" category, but I want to display "Film" (the Root category), I tryed something like

```
getAncestors()
```

with no luck.

Could someone please tell me how to get the root element of the nested set?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->categories = Doctrine::getTable('Categories')->getTree();
$q = Doctrine_core::getTable('Categories')->createQuery('q');
$q->leftJoin('q.Translation qt')->
  addOrderBy('sort ASC')->
  addOrderBy('qt.cat_name ASC'); 

$this->categories->setBaseQuery($q);



foreach($categories->fetchRoots() as $root)
{
    $options = array(
      'root_id' => $root->getCategoryId()
    );
    foreach($categories->fetchTree($options) as $node)
    {
        echo $node->getName();
    }
}
```

Regards,
Max

Comment: @liilo All that is from:

`$this->categories = Doctrine::getTable('Categories')->getTree();
$q = Doctrine_core::getTable('Categories')->createQuery('q');
$q->leftJoin('q.Translation qt')->addOrderBy('sort ASC')->addOrderBy('qt.cat_name ASC');
$this->categories->setBaseQuery($q);`

And we must fetchRoots if the Set is multi root:

`<?php foreach ($categories->fetchRoots() as $root): ?>
    <?php $options = array(
      'root_id' => $root->getCategoryId()
    ); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: Ok i've edited the post because the highliting in the comments is fubared